# Consuming RESTful APIs using Electron

Tags: node.js, rest, spring-boot, electron

I would like to make some requests (GET, POST, PUT ...) for a RESTful API before displaying any window of my Electron application (use Electron app as a client). Is it possible to use [ClientRequest](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/client-request/) to do this? Would anyone has an example?

Thank you very much.